# CentOS/RHEL Init Script (pre-changeroot)

Tags: centos, initramfs

In Debian systems, you can add scripts to `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/`, but, as far as I can tell, there's no equivalent in CentOS. Is there way to inject a script into the initramfs that runs *before* the changeroot to the real system filesystem?